# Problemas con Botones de Tkinter con MAC

Tags: tkinter, macos

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Python 3,11 y en Windows funciona sin problema, pero al instalarla en MAC (Sonoma 14.0) me fallan los botones , no funcionan a la primera , hay que pulsarlos varias veces para que respondan , sobre todo con  los botones desplegables
No consigo dar con la solución, actualicé a las versión 3,11 pero sigue igual
Gracias

Comment: Checa la versión de Python y Tkinter, Mac trae unas instaladas por defecto que son obsoletas, prueba a utilizar Homebrew para instalarlas.

Comment: Hola Carlos, si tras probar con una versión actualizada de Tkinter (te recomiendo usar un entorno virtual, instalar en el tkinter y probar la app en el, así no tienes que tocar la instalacion del sistema) sigues con el problema, te recomiendo agregar tu código a la pregunta o al menos una versión simplificada pero que presente el mismo problema, para que podamos reproducirlo. Ese tipo de comportamientos es por ejemplo típico de usar mas de un mainloop en la app, mala implementación de multithreading, etc

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas , lo tengo instalado en un entorno virtual con 3.11 de python.